# Redux Thunk is not being recognized as a middleware

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm importing thunk from react-thunk, and I'm trying to apply it to my store, however, when I run the code I get error:

> TypeError: middleware is not a function"

I also get this other message:

> const chain = middlewares.map((middleware) => middleware(middlewareAPI));

My code is pretty small:

```
const redux = require("redux");
const createStore = redux.createStore;
const applyMiddleware = redux.applyMiddleware;
const thunkMiddleWare = require("redux-thunk").default;
const axios = require("axios");

const initialState = { loading: false, users: [], error: "" };

const _fetch_users = "fetch_users";
const _fetch_users_success = "fetch_users_success";
const _fetch_users_error = "error";

const fetch_users = () => {
  return {
    type: _fetch_users,
  };
};

const fetch_users_success = (users) => {
  return {
    type: _fetch_users_success,
    payload: users,
  };
};

const fetch_users_error = (error) => {
  return {
    type: _fetch_users_error,
    payload: error,
  };
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case _fetch_users:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    case _fetch_users_success:
      return {
        loading: false,
        users: action.payload,
        error: "",
      };

    case _fetch_users_error:
      return {
        loading: false,
        users: [],
        error: action.payload,
      };
  }
};

const fetchUsers = () => {
  return async function (dispatch) {
    try {
      dispatch(fetch_users());
      const result = await axios.get("jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
      const users = result.data;
      const usersId = users.map((user) => user.id);
      dispatch(fetch_users_success(usersId));
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(fetch_users_error(error.message));
    }
  };
};
const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleWare));

store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()));

store.dispatch(fetchUsers());
```

Where could the error be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting TypeError: middleware is not a function in the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77640251/getting-typeerror-middleware-is-not-a-function-in-the-terminal)

Comment: Yes, thank you!